# Binding from DataTemplate.Triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I am trying to do my binding working for MyAnimation similar to the working one which is MyHeight.
My Height is working properly, but I can not find a way to make the MyAnimation binds to something.

```
    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="MyTemplate"
        DataType="MyNotification">
        <Grid
            x:Name="MyNotificationWindow" ...
            Height="{Binding Path = MyHeight}"
            >
            ....
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger
                RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded"
                SourceName="MyNotificationWindow">
                <BeginStoryboard
                    x:Name="MyStory">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MyNotificationWindow"
                            From="0.01"
                            To="1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            Duration="{Binding Path=MyAnimation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            />
            ....
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the following : `{Binding Path=MyAnimation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` should be `{Binding Path=DataContext.MyAnimation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Try this, it might be the issue.

Comment: Then, move the trigger in the grid's style. It will be easier since you won't have to specify the Control and you will have access to the grid's DataContext.

Comment: I will try, but I prefer to find a way to bind to what i need. thanks for your input